# My gitignore_global is not working even though gitconfig specify the absolute path

Tags: git, gitignore

I created a .gitignore_global file in `~/Users/Tony/.gitignore_global`, which is also the path where the `.gitconfig` is stored.

This is what is inside the `.gitconfig`:

```
[core]
    excludesfile = ~/.gitignore_global
```

This is what is inside the `.gitignore_global`:

```
# Compiled source #
###################
*.com
*.class
*.dll
*.exe
*.o
*.so

# Packages #
############
# it's better to unpack these files and commit the raw source
# git has its own built in compression methods
*.7z
*.dmg
*.gz
*.iso
*.jar
*.rar
*.tar
*.zip

# Logs and databases #
######################
*.log
*.sql
*.sqlite

# OS generated files #
######################
.DS_Store
.DS_Store?
._*
.Spotlight-V100
.Trashes
ehthumbs.db
Thumbs.db

# CocoaPods #
#############
Pods

# SVN #
#######
*.svn
.svn/*

# Xcode #
#########
build/
DerivedData
profile
xcuserdata
!default.mode1v3
!default.mode2v3
!default.pbxuser
!default.perspectivev3
*.mode1
*.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
*.moved-aside
*~.nib
*.pbxuser
*.perspective
*.perspectivev3
*.swp
*.xccheckout
```

I do not understand why the `.gitignore_global` file isn't working. The `.DS_Store` files are still being detected by git.
I had already tried comments like "`git rm --cached .DS_Store`" and tried others solutions found on Stack Overflow, however git is still detecting the `.DS_Store` files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be sure your global gitignore is taken into account:

- make sure you have git 2.8+
- do a `git config --show-origin -l|grep excludesfile` to see if your rule is there (if there is one below it involving `excludesfile`, it would override yours).
- try and put a full path in your global config for the `excludefile`: `/home/<user>/.gitignore_global` instead of '`~`'.
- do a `git check-ignore -v -- path/to/.DS_Store` to see if any ignore rule is displayed.

Since the OP confirms this is working in a new repo, that means the current elements are tracked in the existing repo.
For instance:

```
git rm --cached -r .DS_Store
```

Instead, the [OP Tony Ong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5694138/tony-ong) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36930938/my-gitignore-global-is-not-working-even-though-gitconfig-specify-the-absolute-pa/36931125?noredirect=1#comment61547972_36931125):

> I took a round about to solve the problem with regards to "existing repo".
>   I went to copy the content in the repo to a `temp` folder, delete the content in the repo, commit/push the repo, copy the content from temp folder to repo, commit/ push again.
>   It is a tedious process but it works, `gitignore_global` is now working for existing repo.
>   I will try "`git rm --cached -r .DS_Store`" when the opportunity arise.

Comment: I did a "git config --show-origin -l|grep excludesfile" and the terminal return me - file:/usr/local/git/etc/gitconfig core.excludesfile=~/.gitignore
- file:/Users/Tony/.gitconfig  core.excludesfile=/Users/Tony/.gitignore_global there is one below it involving "excludesfile", does it means it will override mine?

Comment: I did some testing, however the .gitignore_global is not working. I completed point 1 and 3 of yours. don't quite understand point 2 but still run the command and pasted the result earlier on. tried running point 4 but it isn't working.

Comment: @TonyOng Can you initialize a new repo anywhere you want? `giti init newrepo; cd newrepo`, and create one of the file which should be ignored: a `git status` should *not* show that file (no add or commit necessary)

Comment: it works for the testing new repo file. however for existing repo, it isn't working. I am thinking i need to untracked the .DS_Store from git in those existing repo first.

Comment: @TonyOng I confirm: `git rm --chached -r .DS_STore`

Comment: thanks VonC. I took a round about to solve the problem with regards to "existing repo". I went to copy the content in the repo to a temp folder, delete the content in the repo, commit/push the repo, copy the content from temp folder to repo, commit/ push again. It a tedious process but it works, gitignore_global is now working for existing repo. I will try "git rm --cached -r .DS_Store" when the opportunity arise. thanks man! :)

Comment: @TonyOng Thank you for this feedback. I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.